# C++ restore/pass a vector (what to call in the header?)

Tags: c++, function, vector, return

I am learning C++ at school and I am adding some functions to my school project. We need to code a program, which searches a word in files in folders.

I am at the point, where I want to list all directories and files and pass them back (with return), so I can display (output) them at the console.

So I used a vector type string and pushed back all the paths I found...
Then I wanted to give (pass) them back with return, but I got the Error:

```
error: cannot convert `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >' to `std::string*' in return
```

Here is some Code:

```
string OpenFolder(string path, const string constSearchedWord)


vector<string> vIndex;         //Vektor erzeugen
vector<string>::iterator i;    //Iterator (zum durchlaufen)
```

...

```
while ( 0 != ( dirEntry = readdir( dirHandle ) ) )
    {
        string name = dirEntry->d_name;
        fullPath = path + '\\' + name;
        vIndex.push_back(fullPath);
    }
    //Den Ordner schliessen
    closedir( dirHandle );
```

...
If I wanted to write it into the console in this function:

```
for (i = vIndex.begin(); i < vIndex.end(); ++i)
{
    cout << static_cast<string>(*i) << endl;
}
```

is working easily, but I don't want to write it in this function into the console.

I want to do

```
return vIndex;
```

I think the problem is in the header:

```
string OpenFolder(string path, const string constSearchedWord)
```

I tried

```
vector OpenFolder(string path, const string constSearchedWord)
```

But this didn't work either.

I don't know what to set here:

```
->???<- OpenFolder(string path, const string constSearchedWord)
```

Comment: You are most definitely not learning C. C has no `std::vector`.

Comment: BTW, if the variable you're returning is a `vector<string>`, then isn't it kind of obvious that the return value also needs to be a `vector<string>`?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant well, of course. I dont know, how I could forgot this...But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type of function `OpenFolder`

```
string OpenFolder(string path, const string constSearchedWord)
~~~~~ should be std::vector < std::string >
```

Also,

use `const` reference for function arguments

```
std::vector<std::string> OpenFolder(const string& path,
                                    const string& constSearchedWord )
```

Comment: sorry, but why the `string&`, where is the differents to `string` ?

Comment: @Sinmson That's a reference. Google "C++ reference" if you don't recognize the term.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant ok, thanks. I searched it and know why this is better in the theory. But is there a differens in the praxis, for real?

Comment: @Sinmson Sometimes there is, sometimes there isn't. But does it matter? I doubt. When this becomes a *measurable* bottleneck, only then think about it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return the vector of strings from a method then the return type needs to be a vector of strings i.e.

`std::vector<std::string> OpenFolder(string path, const string constSearchedWord)`

Answer (score 0):

A function definition/declaration generally takes the form of ...

```
[return type] [function name]([arguments])
```

If you're returning `vIndex` from the `OpenFolder` function then the return type needs to match the type of `vIndex`, which is `vector<string>`.